# JAIN-SIP support for RFC 7339

Tags: java, sip, rfc, jain-sip

Is there any way to **add custom via header in jain-sip**? Adding the oc-parametrs from [RFC 7339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7339).
From [enter link description here](http://otherendoftheline.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/why-jain-sip-sucks-custom-headers/)place I got the following example, but not sure if it will work. The quote from link:

> This could be easily achieved by adding some code to implementation of
> javax.sip.message.Message.addHeader(Header header) function.

```
void addHeader(Header header) {
    if(!(header instanceof InternalHeaderObject)
        && header instanceof ExtensionHeader) {
            ExtensionHeader extensionHeader = (ExtensionHeader) header;
            header = headerFactory.createHeader(extensionHeader.getName(), extensionHeader.getValue());
        }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start by saying you can absolutely handle custom via headers in terms of SIP as long as it is valid SIP. For this RFC you just need to use viaHeader.set/getParameter if I am not missing something.

The blog post talks about creating your own header classes, which is not relevant to your needs as far as I can imagine. Custom header classes are tricky and inefficient. For example JAIN SIP will automatically construct it's own ViaHeader instance for inbound messages when parsing them. Plugging a custom header to override the default Via internally will break a lot of validation promises and cause overhead..

If you have a showstopper case for custom header classes I will gladly listen though.

Comment: As I understand the RFC. The sip messages should be something like that: INVITE sips:user@example.com SIP/2.0 Via: SIP/2.0/TLSp1.example.net;branch=z9hG4bK2d4790.1;oc;oc-algo="loss,A“; So I need to ad several params to via-header.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there is no viaHeader.setParameter...correct me please, if I'm wrong. Here is the link for viaHeader class: https://developer.opencloud.com/devportal/devportal/apis/jainsip/1.1/docs/javax/sip/header/ViaHeader.html

Comment: The parameter setters and getters come from one of the interfaces inherited by ViaHeader called Parameters https://developer.opencloud.com/devportal/devportal/apis/jainsip/1.1/docs/javax/sip/header/Parameters.html